# Can the MVC Design Pattern / architectural pattern be used in Desktop Application Development?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, winforms, model-view-controller, desktop-application

I've just learned what ASP.NET MVC is and I'm wondering if the pattern is ever used in Windows Desktop application development?

I'm specifically looking at potentially trying to use it in a Desktop .NET application.

Please forgive me if this question is way out in left field in terms of how MVC is suppose to be used. I'm still trying to wrap my head around the details of it.

Comment: The MVC architecture was popularized (maybe invented?) with SmallTalk, along with OOP and GUI frameworks.  It's definitely a desktop-app thing.  it was shoehorned into web apps, and only makes sense after a big redefinition of the terms.

Comment: More than that. MVC is UI platform agnostic. You can do web, voice, desktop or console apps. That the goal of MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC comes in many flavors, Marting Fowler discusses at http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html

Google returns quite a lot of interesting stuff for [windows forms mvc](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+forms+mvc) also

Answer (score 6):

The [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) Pattern works like a dream with "desktop" apps, as you don't have to worry about handling state information.

Comment: Thank you.  I had to select the Hates_'s answer because of the link.  But I still thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 4):

Most definitely. Here is a list of [MVC GUI frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller#Implementations_of_MVC_as_GUI_frameworks).

Answer (score 0):

I don't rememer where I see a good example of MVC for descktop apps.
It was about a thermometer.
The model was the thermometer it self. A simple POJO with the current state of temperature.
The apps have several views and controllers of the thermometer.
The controllers calls the setters, and the views calls the getters.
To synch the app use the Observer pattern. The views subscribe to the model.
And the model notify all the views subscribed in each setter.

It was a very useful example for understand MVC.

Answer (score 0):

**For others whom might be interested:**

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/BuildingModelViewPresenterAapplicationsWithMVCFramework.aspx

http://www.mvcsharp.org/Getting_started_with_MVCSharp/Default.aspx